# Anyone else having issues with SceneBuilder in IntelliJ Mac OS (Catalina)?

Tags: java, spring, javafx, javafx-8

I have two issues, one dragging anything causes the scenebuilder within IntelliJ to freeze or Hang when dragging any element on to the page, which I then have to close the FXML file and try again. This issue is only present on Mac as I can't replicate it on windows I have tried so many things and have been at it for a month. From VM options, clean installs, new jdks, inbuilt jdk from JetBrains with FX preinstalled and more. 
The second issue is a ClassDefNotFound which only occurs in the ultimate edition of EAP IntelliJ (2020.1) but works on the community edition.

The link below is my current journey and additional information with my issue. If anyone can offer any help with this I'd appreciate it as its caused a great deal of stress for me.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232738

Comment: Have you tried the [standalone version of _Scene Builder_](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/)? Not sure how maintained the JavaFX IntelliJ plugin is.

Comment: Hi, I know the problem you are dealing with. You can open your FXML-File directly from inside IntelliJ by clicking on it and selecting ->Open with SceneBuilder. After that SceneBuilder will open your layout. You can edit your layout and save the changes. All changes are going to be updated to you FXML-File in your project. Opening the file directly in SceneBuilder also gives you more options. Had the same problem on Windows OS.

Comment: Yeah that’s basically what I’m doing right now using the external scene builder but it’s so frustrating that they haven’t fixed this issue and it’s not something that I’ve just found it’s been here for two years.